# Insert booking using start time and duration?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of booking which has the following fields:

```
bookingId, bookingUserId, bookingYachtId, bookingDate, bookingDate, bookingStartTime, bookingCheckOutTime
```

My question is how to insert record if the startTime is 23:00:00 and
duration of the booking is 4:00:00 hours and bookingDate is 2018-02-25, because in this record the date can also change, so how can I insert the record?

I need to insert the record properly, because I am using this table to
check if yacht is available for the booking.

note bookingCheckOutTime is the sum of startTime And duration

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: What have you tried? Post your own code.

Comment: i know how to insert please read my question i am having trouble in a particular scenario

Comment: i am using codeingiter and just insert the record normally nothing special

Comment: They're columns btw

Comment: You have two columns with the same name. Also , store dates and times as a single entity

Answer (score -1):

Add 4 hours to bookingDateTime while inserting a record (**MySql**):

```
DATE_ADD($bookingDateTime, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
```

Or you can do it in **php** :

```
$bookingCheckoutTime = date($bookingdateTime, strtotime('+4 hours'));
```